# Active tab changes after save in Joomla administrator

Tags: joomla-3.x, development

I have created a new component. At the administrator backend, the active tab goes back to the first tab (which was declared in edit.php) when I click on 'save' after I have modified a field in another tab.

I trace my codes, and it follows similarly to that in contents `(/article/views/tmpl/edit.php)` and weblinks `(/weblink/views/tmpl/edit.php)`, where the active tab works; meaning it stays at the same tab after "save". I am using Joomla 3.3.6

## Here's an extract of my codes...

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

// Include the component HTML helpers.
JHtml::addIncludePath(JPATH_COMPONENT . '/helpers/html');

JHtml::_('behavior.formvalidation');
// JHtml::_('behavior.keepalive');
JHtml::_('formbehavior.chosen', 'select');

?>

<script type="text/javascript">
Joomla.submitbutton = function(task)
{
    if (task == 'subscription.cancel' ||     document.formvalidator.isValid(document.id('item-form')))
    {
        <?php echo $this->form->getField('description')->save(); ?>
        Joomla.submitform(task, document.getElementById('item-form'));
    }
}
</script>

<form action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php? option=com_subscriptions&view=subscription&layout=edit&id='.(int) $this->item->id); ?>" method="post" name="adminForm" id="item-form" class="form-validate">

<?php echo JLayoutHelper::render('joomla.edit.title_alias', $this); ?>

  <div class="form-horizontal">
<?php echo JHtml::_('bootstrap.startTabSet', 'myTab', array('active' => 'general')); ?>         

    <?php echo JHtml::_('bootstrap.addTab', 'myTab', 'general', empty($this->item->id) ? JText::_('COM_SUBSCRIPTIONS_NEW_SUBSCRIPTION', true) : JText::_('COM_SUBSCRIPTIONS_EDIT_SUBSCRIPTION', $this->item->id, true)); ?>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span9">
......

    <input type="hidden" name="task" value="" />
```

Answer (score 2):

On the third last line above

```
    <?php echo JHtml::_('bootstrap.addTab', 'myTab', 'general', empty($this->item->id) ? JText::_('COM_SUBSCRIPTIONS_NEW_SUBSCRIPTION', true) : JText::_('COM_SUBSCRIPTIONS_EDIT_SUBSCRIPTION', $this->item->id, true)); ?>
```

I think it should be

```
JText::sprintf('COM_SUBSCRIPTIONS_EDIT_SUBSCRIPTION', $this->item->id, true)
```

instead of

```
JText::_('COM_SUBSCRIPTIONS_EDIT_SUBSCRIPTION', $this->item->id, true)
```

Answer (score 1):

I added the following code to my administrator/component/com_/view/ file:

```
/* tab memory */
jQuery(function($) {
  var json, tabsState;
  $('a[data-toggle="pill"], a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown', function(e) {
    var href, json, parentId, tabsState;

    tabsState = localStorage.getItem("tabs-state");
    json = JSON.parse(tabsState || "{}");
    parentId = $(e.target).parents("ul.nav.nav-pills, ul.nav.nav-tabs").attr("id");
    href = $(e.target).attr('href');
    json[parentId] = href;

    return localStorage.setItem("tabs-state", JSON.stringify(json));
  });

  tabsState = localStorage.getItem("tabs-state");
  json = JSON.parse(tabsState || "{}");

  $.each(json, function(containerId, href) {
    return $("#" + containerId + " a[href=" + href + "]").tab('show');
  });

  $("ul.nav.nav-pills, ul.nav.nav-tabs").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if (!json[$this.attr("id")]) {
      return $this.find("a[data-toggle=tab]:first, a[data-toggle=pill]:first").tab("show");
    }
  });
});
```

from this discussion:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16984739/1729791
and its working for me

Answer (score -3):

Add this in top: `JHtml::_('behavior.tabstate');`

Comment: I don't know enough to claim that this answer is incorrect, but the 2 downvotes give some indication.  Beyond the correctness, whenever you wish to post an answer here, please take care to include a thoughtful and educational explanation of why/how your solution works (to the best of your knowledge).